# How to read a JSON column as a field in Apache PIG

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I'm trying to read a movie dataset I got from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset/discussion/42011) using Apache Pig. One of the .csv files is named "keywords.csv" and it has tuples like this:

```
862,[{'id': 931, 'name': 'jealousy'}, {'id': 4290, 'name': 'toy'}, {'id': 5202, 'name': 'boy'}, {'id': 6054, 'name': 'friendship'}, {'id': 9713, 'name': 'friends'}, {'id': 9823, 'name': 'rivalry'}, {'id': 165503, 'name': 'boy next door'}, {'id': 170722, 'name': 'new toy'}, {'id': 187065, 'name': 'toy comes to life'}]
8844,[{'id': 10090, 'name': 'board game'}, {'id': 10941, 'name': 'disappearance'}, {'id': 15101, 'name': "based on children's book"}, {'id': 33467, 'name': 'new home'}, {'id': 158086, 'name': 'recluse'}, {'id': 158091, 'name': 'giant insect'}]
.
.
.
```

The first field is the id of the movie, and the second field is a JSON like string with keywords related to that movie and their ids. The file separator in all the .csv files of the dataset is a comma, but when it comes to loading the keywords.csv it causes a problem. Here is how I'm trying to load the table:

```
keywords = load 'dataset/keywords.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, keywords:chararray);
fltr = filter keywords by id == 862;

DUMP fltr;
```

That only prints `(862,"[{'id': 931)` when I was expecting it to print something like this:

```
(862,[{'id': 931, 'name': 'jealousy'}, {'id': 4290, 'name': 'toy'}, {'id': 5202, 'name': 'boy'}, {'id': 6054, 'name': 'friendship'}, {'id': 9713, 'name': 'friends'}, {'id': 9823, 'name': 'rivalry'}, {'id': 165503, 'name': 'boy next door'}, {'id': 170722, 'name': 'new toy'}, {'id': 187065, 'name': 'toy comes to life'}])
```

So that I could save the column keywords in a new file with the .json extension and then use the `JsonLoader()` to extract the keywords.

How should I go about doing this? Or is it even possible to read keywords directly without having to to save it to a external .json file? Thank You.

---

## UPDATE 1

Just found out about maps in Apache pig, here is my latest try:

```
keywords = load 'dataset/keywords.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, keywords:[{keyId:int,name:chararray}]);
```

That throws an error: `Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use Twitter's [Elephant Bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird) to parse a single json column in Pig. (If you wanted to parse files that are json-only, you could simply use Pig's [JsonLoader API](http://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/func.html#jsonloadstore)).

Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847058/json-array-field-handling-in-elephant-bird-udf-in-pig) - it looks like your json is also an array, so what's written there will apply for you, too.

In case that doesn't work, here's [a blog post describing how to write a Python UDF for a more specific case of JSON parsing](http://dmtolpeko.com/2016/11/11/parsing-json-columns-in-apache-pig/). You can of course do the same thing with a Java UDF.